# DocuSign Rooms API Export Room to C# Console App

Tags: c#, docusignapi

Using the DocuSign code-examples-csharp, you can export Room data to JSON.  I need to batch export Room data using a C# console app without using the website.  I'm unclear how to convert this web application to a console app.  Are there examples of this somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, for a console app you will want to use JWT. The C# repo you can use JWT, so confirm this is working for you. With JWT there's no need for user to login.
You can then take the Auth Code from JWTAuth.cs and the example code from ExportDataFromRoom.cs and add them to your console app.

This should work if you also include the configuration information for auth.

We soon plan to add the Rooms API to the VS Extension that will make this even easier.